# How does $\log_{1/b}x$ become $- \log_b(x).$?

Tags: logarithms

I understand the other case $$\log _x\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-1 $$ but when the log is to the base of a fraction, I don't know how to prove so it is true

Comment: A side remark: Be conscious that this kind of exercise is very academical: bases of logarithms that are $<1$ are **never** used in practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that $- \log_b x = \log_{\frac{1}{b}} x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466283/how-to-show-that-log-b-x-log-frac1b-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log_x y=\frac{\log x}{\log y}$$
So $$\log_{1/b}x =\frac{\log x}{\log (1/b)}=\frac{\log x}{-\log b}=-\log_b x$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $b^y=x\iff (1/b)^{-y}=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Solving it for a very general case as follows:

[image]

Now to get your result, just put n=-1

Answer (score 0):

By definition

$$y=\log_{1/b}x \iff\left(\frac 1 b\right)^y=x\iff \frac 1 {b^y}=x \iff\frac1x=b^y \iff x=b^{-y}\iff -y=\log_b x$$